# Google Play Bucket not shown in the Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play, storage, bucket

I am trying to load some Google Play reports to my BigQuery project, but having issues with finding the bucket in the Could Storage.

1. I have copied the Cloud Storage URL in the Google Play console (gs://pubsite_prod_rev_... format)
2. When I open my Cloud Storage this bucket is not in the list of available buckets.
3. But if I enter this URL in the Data Transfer from bucket to dataset, it will work (although not all reports will be loaded to to my dataset :( )
4. If I enter this URL in the Data Transfer from bucket to bucket, it won't work, because the transfer lacks some permissions to the source bucket. But I cannot change the permissions to this Google Play bucket because I can't see it in my buckets list.

So my question is - what could be the reason this bucket is not displayed in my storage and how to get access to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Maria,

I'm facing the same issue, 'but'. There's a workaround to view the contents of your pub site_prod_X by visiting the bucket URL:

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/pubsite_prod_X . It's strange it's not being shown and I'm still figuring out how to download the contents with a client.

Comment: Hi @rwzdoorn, Were you able to change the permissions to that bucket?